# How to copy an XML using XSLT to produce another new XML of the same form

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath

After perform 3 level sort an XML document using XSLT. I am unable to make a copy of my sorted xml. My original XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>5</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>9</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>5</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>5</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>9</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>3</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>2</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>2</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>4</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>6</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>2</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>4</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>2</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>2</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>10</TestParameter>
    </Test>

    <Test>
    <TestPhase>2</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>2</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    </Test>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </Root>
```

After 3 level sort, I made a copy of it. but the new XML (test.xml) appear to be the following:

```
<Test><TestPhase>3</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>3</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>4</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>4</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>4</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>4</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>5</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>5</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>5</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>5</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>6</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>6</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>6</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>6</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>7</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>7</TestPhase><TestFlow>1</TestFlow><TestParameter>2</TestParameter></Test><Test><TestPhase>7</TestPhase><TestFlow>2</TestFlow><TestParameter>1</TestParameter></Test><Test><    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

please advice me on this.  I am new to XPath / XSLT.  My XSLT is written as the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="TestPhase" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestFlow" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestParameter" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also check my code with the method of just make a copy the original XML, without sorting it.  The same problem occur.  I have try with the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The word :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

does not appear on the first line although I am using

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

And it is all crumble up athough I choose :

```
indent="yes"
```

Please help.  Your help is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Cheers :)

Comment: How are you actually performing the XSLT transforming? What XSLT processor are you using? Note that the indentation (or lack of) is not actually done by the XSLT process itself, but by what ever serializes the result as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the "word" you refer to is the xml declaration. To include it in your output you should add "omit-xml-declaration" to the `xsl:output` statement (along with "standalone" if you want that included in the declaration)

```
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" standalone="yes" />
```

However, this initially won't work because for the output XML document to be standalone it must be well-formed, with a single root element. Your current template matching `Root` is not copying that element.

Additionally, by doing `xsl:apply-templates` you are selecting all child nodes of `Root`, but that includes the whitespace nodes, not just the `Test` elements. To solve this, you can either explicitly select `Test` elements, by doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="Test">`. Alternatively, you could remove whitespace-only nodes from the XML by adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` to the XSLT.

Try this XSLT, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" standalone="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Test">
      <xsl:sort select="TestPhase" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestFlow" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestParameter" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for the actual result not being indented, this depends on how the result of the transform is being serialised. If you are using C# (I've made this assumption based on a previous question you asked), you might need to check you are passing the xslt output settings to the XmlWriter. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.outputsettings(v=vs.110).aspx where it gives this example:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(stylesheet);
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(filename);
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, xslt.OutputSettings);
xslt.Transform(doc, writer);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Many thanks to Tim C.  I finally able to get my XML generated with indented document elements and also the declaration.  However, there is still a minor defect, the standalone="yes" is not there although I follow your method.  But, really really thank you very much, Tim C. Cheers from newbuntu !